# Maria DB stored procedure not returning anything

Tags: mariadb

When I call this stored procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AGBBeta.TestReturnOptions(IN pOptionsID INT, IN pQty Int, IN pUserId INT,
    OUT outParam NVARCHAR(3))
BEGIN
    DECLARE CalcGlobalCHECK NVarchar(3);        
    DECLARE done INT DEFAULT FALSE;
    DECLARE iMaterialsId INTEGER;
    DECLARE iRangesID INTEGER;          
    DECLARE iSec1 INTEGER;
    DECLARE dSQM Decimal(9,2);
    DECLARE dSlabQty Decimal(9,2);
    DECLARE iMitreLog INTEGER;
    DECLARE dSlabOverPrice Decimal(9,2);
    DECLARE dPriceOver Decimal(9,2);
    DECLARE iOptionsID2 INTEGER;
    
    DECLARE materials_cursor CURSOR FOR 
            SELECT MaterialsID, RangesID, Sec1, SQM, SlabQty, MitreLog, SlabOverPrice, PriceOver, OptionsID2 FROM AGBBeta.Materials WHERE OptionsID = pOptionsID;   

    SET CalcGlobalCHECK = '000';
    INSERT INTO STORED_PROCEDURED_CHECK(SP_Name, pOptionsID, pQty, pUserId,ValueName,Value)
            VALUES ('TestReturnOptions', pOptionsID, pQty, pUserId,'CalcGlobalCHECK_1',CalcGlobalCHECK);
    
 OPEN materials_cursor;

        materials_cursor_loop: LOOP
            FETCH materials_cursor INTO iMaterialsId, iRangesID, iSec1, dSQM, dSlabQty, iMitreLog, dSlabOverPrice, dPriceOver, iOptionsID2;
        
            IF done THEN
                SET CalcGlobalCHECK = '002';
                INSERT INTO STORED_PROCEDURED_CHECK(SP_Name, pOptionsID, pQty, pUserId,ValueName,Value)
                VALUES ('TestReturnOptions', pOptionsID, pQty, pUserId,'CalcGlobalCHECK_4',CalcGlobalCHECK);
                LEAVE materials_cursor_loop;
            END IF; 
           
           INSERT INTO STORED_PROCEDURED_CHECK(SP_Name, pOptionsID, pQty, pUserId,ValueName,Value)
            VALUES ('TestReturnOptions', pOptionsID, pQty, pUserId,'CalcGlobalCHECK_2',CalcGlobalCHECK);
           
            SET CalcGlobalCHECK = '001';
        
        END LOOP materials_cursor_loop; 
    
        CLOSE materials_cursor;
    
    INSERT INTO STORED_PROCEDURED_CHECK(SP_Name, pOptionsID, pQty, pUserId,ValueName,Value)
            VALUES ('TestReturnOptions', pOptionsID, pQty, pUserId,'CalcGlobalCHECK_3',CalcGlobalCHECK);
    
        SET outParam =  CalcGlobalCHECK;
     
     SELECT outParam;

END
```

by using

```
CALL AGBBeta.TestReturnOptions(26610, 1, 4, @a_message);
```

I get this error

> SQL Error [1329] [02000]: (conn=358) No data - zero rows fetched, selected, or processed

If I check the table I write the values into I can see CalcGlobalCHECK_1 and CalcGlobalCHECK_2 but nothing else.

If I remove the  OPEN materials_cursor; to CLOSE materials_cursor; bit it all works fine.

But I need to do calcs on the figures returned in the cursor.

What am I missing to make this work?

Comment: Like [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78031333/tryiing-to-read-multiple-results-sets-from-mariadb-using-c-connector-command/78031417#78031417) are you missing CLIENT_MULTI_RESULTS on connection?

Comment: danblack I'm not sure I'm a bit new to Maria DBs I'm using DBeaver to connect and create the SP.

Comment: How is `done` set?  Does the loop do anything other than set `CalcGlobalCHECK`?  It can probably be done without a cursor loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is from calling FETCH when there are no more rows.

You should set a handler to catch this and set done:

```
DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET done=TRUE;
```